# What is the proper way of add the content of the directory where the dockerfile is?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know that usually, one adds a directory with `COPY` or `ADD`. What if I want to add the contents of the directory where the dockerfile is (including the dockerfile itself) in the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `.` for the current directory:

```
COPY . /build-context/
```

That would copy your build context to the image into a destination directory called `/build-context`. I call it build context rather than your current directory because that's the source of a COPY command. Docker is client/server based, so the client where you are running the `docker` command from may be different than the server where the build is performed. You see this when you run a docker build, there's an initial packaging of the build context and then sending that to the potentially remote build server. You control the build context with the last arg to the build command:

```
docker build -t your_image .
```

The `.` at the end of the build command sends the current directory to the backend as the context. But this could be a different directory, or even a remote git repo, so make sure this is set as desired before attempting the above COPY command.

Comment: So `COPY . /build-context/` will work only if I build with `docker build -t your_image .`?

Comment: @gvgramazio If you did a `docker build -t your_image some_other_dir`, then `COPY . /some_image_path` would copy the contents of `some_other_dir` to `/some_image_path`.

Comment: So, is using `COPY . /build-context/` the right thing to do? The alternative would be to use an absolute path but I think that it's even worse.

Comment: @gvgramazio `COPY . /SomePath/` is the same as `COPY / /SomePath/`. Your "working directory" inside the build context is always the root of the context. I just find the latter notation confusing since many assume / is the root of the host or container, rather than the root of the build context.